# What are some BI tools that integrate well with Sharepoint 2007?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, business-intelligence

We currently use MOSS 2007 for our company intranet site and we are looking to create dashboards for performance kpi's etc. Weve been using SSRS 2005, Cognos as well as excel services and BDC. I've demoed Dundas Dashboard as it comes with a sharepoint web part for viewing dashboards in SharePoint. Are there any other BI platforms out there that integrate well with Sharepoint 2007?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PerformancePoint was integrated into 2010, but as of 2007 you have to buy it separate. Its a very good BI package.

Comment: Performance Point Server is what I was thinking about. So you would recommend that for MOSS 2007 above Dundas or Qlikview?

Answer (score 0):

Our team just finished a large project that uses SSRS 2008 R2 with SharePoint 2007. It's a collection of dashboard pages containing a variety of KPIs, graphs, and tables. The reports run against an SSAS data warehouse. You can run SSRS in SharePoint integrated mode, but for this project, the reports were encapsulated within a custom web part against SSRS in native mode. You cannot do analytics, but anything that you can do with SSRS (which can include "drill-down" and other iteractivity in the report) you can include into a SharePoint website. All the dashboard pages look great, run quickly, and visually integrate right in with SharePoint. I'd love to include a screenshot, but I can't because of the sensitive data in the reports.

Comment: Yes I've heard SSRS 2008 has alot of improvements over 2005. Unfortunately we will not be upgrading to 2008 for a while. We are still in the process of going to 2005. Im going to recommend PerformancePoint. Thanks for your input.